# display bootstrap popup modal when entering data in input field

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

I'm using bootstrap modal popup in my angular application(typescript).
i have to pass entered code in input field the moment it is typed  as a parameter to a service to search for the user information found with the same code , those data will display in the popup but i want it to be display the moment i finish typing the code in the input . can that be possible

here is what i tried but didn't work

```
 <input (keyup.enter)="Search()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" [(ngModel)]="codeuser" type="text" >
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-modal-input-value-nwxjs2?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) for a input that triggers value after you finished typing.
You can use [debounceTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime), you can basically provide  a time between event subscriptions. so you can do something like this.

**1. Using Form Control**

```
 this.firstNameControl.valueChanges
    .debounceTime(1000)
    .subscribe(newValue => {
      this.codeuser = newValue
    });
```

in html

```
<input (keyup.enter)="Search()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" 
[formControl]="firstNameControl" type="text"  >
```

In your Search method, you can open up the modal

```
 Search() {
    console.log(this.codeuser);
    this.showModal();
    // call service or do whatever you want using the codeuser variable
  }
```

**2. Using ngModel**: If you want to use ngModel, you can use [subjects](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject). so whenever there is a change in input field, the subject can emit this value. And in the same component you can listen to this emitted value and apply debounceTime as well as another rxjs operator- [distinctUntilChanged](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/distinctUntilChanged)

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.modelChanged
      .debounceTime(1000)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .subscribe((value: string) => {
        console.log(value);
        this.codeuser = value;
      });
  }

  inputChanged(event) {
    this.modelChanged.next(event);
  }
```

And in the html file

```
<input (keyup.enter)="Search()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
[ngModel]="codeuser" (ngModelChange)="inputChanged($event)" type="text">
```

Comment: thank you , but what i'm trying to do is display a popup form when the value is entered

Comment: when you press the enter key after typing in input field?

Comment: i updated the stackblitz, so after you enter something and press enter it will open the popup.

Comment: Great!, I updated my answer, can you accept it?

Comment: okay i will , is this the part that keeps the popup wait until you enter the name ?

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    this.firstNameControl.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(1000)
      .subscribe(newValue => {
        this.codeuser = newValue;
      });
  }

Comment: because i tried to do the same without the ngOninit code but the poput gets displays before typing

Comment: Yes. This valuechanges actually listens to every value change in input and wait for sometime before emiting the value to next event.

Comment: how can i adapt it to my input using  ngModel , i tried this :     this.codeuser.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(1000)   , but i get this error : Property 'valueChanges' does not exist on type 'string'

Comment: so instead of using [(ngModel]] you can break them into 2 events, [ngModel]="codeuser" will act as an input binding meaning reflecting the lastest value  of codeuser in input, (ngModelChange)="someMethod()" will be called whenever there's a change in input.

Comment: i'm using angular 12 and i did the same as you did with both formcontrol and ngModel but none of them worked , can the version i'm using be the reason since you are working with angular 12

Comment: whats the issue you are facing?

Comment: the popup modal always shows before typing on the input , and when i remove this  :data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" i doesn't show , but i want  it to be shown after clicking on input

Comment: or is there any other way to toggle the popup prom typescript code without having to specify the toggle ( data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal")on the input

Comment: Question 1) Are you following the same steps as in stackblitz shared?
Question 2) You want to open the popup after clicking on input? Or after pressing enter key?

Comment: yes i did exactly the same as you using formcontroll , answer2: i want to open popup after pressing enter key

Comment: Can you share a stackblitz?